# How to write a query for fetching from two table in a single field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

one table is for storing video course details and the other table is for storing audio course details

here is the table create structure

for audio

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audio_master` (
  `audio_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audio_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`audio_id`)
) 



INSERT INTO `audio_master` (`audio_id`, `audio_title`, `course_id`) VALUES
(1, 'java audio', 1),
(1, 'java audio2', 1);
```

for video

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_master` (
      `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `video_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `course_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
    ) 

INSERT INTO `video_master` (`video_id`, `video_title`, `course_id`) VALUES
    (1, 'java video', 1),
    (1, 'java video2', 1);
```

I have to show one audio and one video simultaneously in the following way

```
Course Materials

java video
java Audio
java Video1
java Audio1
```

How to write a query for fetching this way

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Is course_id a foreign key? Otherwise what links the two tables?

Comment: I'd try a UNION ALL.

Comment: course_id is a foregin key

Comment: select video_title as title , audio_title as title its showing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data in the 2 tables is not related (you are not expecting it to be joined together but just need to create one list from both tables) it is as simple as:

```
SELECT video_title FROM video_master
UNION ALL
SELECT audio_title FROM audio_master
```